# Renci.SshNet can not connect due to error

Tags: vb.net, ssh, ssh.net

I have the following simple code, which however does not work:

```
Imports Renci.SshNet

Public Class ClassTriggerSender

    Public Sub SendTrigger()

        Dim connInfo As New Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("172.20.47.72", "developer", "developer")

        Dim sshClient As New Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo)

        Dim cmd As Renci.SshNet.SshCommand

        sshClient.Connect()

        cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("dir")

        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result)

        sshClient.Disconnect()

    End Sub

End Class
```

My aim is to simply send SSH commands to execute commands on an linux shell.

This is the error message:

[image]

I have found this on stack overflow: [Renci.sshnet : No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (publickey,keyboard-interactive) in Vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478291/renci-sshnet-no-suitable-authentication-method-found-to-complete-authenticatio)

However using this code, I get a similar error:

[image]

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us a log file from any SSH client that is able to authenticate using the same credentials.

Answer (score -1):

For me this is a working method

```
Dim ssh As Renci.SshNet.SshClient
ssh = New SshClient(host, port, username, password)
    Try
        ssh.Connect()
        ssh.RunCommand(script)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```